# What is the origin of the Mormon Temple Ceremony and how has it changed throughout the years?

Tags: lds, freemasonry

I understand that there is a difference between being a Mormon and being a Temple Mormon (one who has gone through the Temple Ceremony at least once and maintains Temple worthiness).

I also understand that it is quite similar to the Masonic Temple Ceremonies and that Joseph Smith was himself a mason.

Where exactly, then, did this Temple Ceremony come from?  Has it changed throughout the years and, if so, how specifically has it changed?

Comment: [discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1949/discussion-between-mason-wheeler-and-narnian)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are more than one LDS Temple covenants.

These include:

- Baptism (for the dead)
- Endowment (including washing and anointing on first visit)
- Confirmation
- Ordination to higher offices of the priesthood (and ordination to Elder on behalf of the dead)
- Marriage and eternal family sealings

I'm assuming you're referring to the endowment covenant.

From the lds.org page on [Temples](http://lds.org/ldsorg/v/index.jsp?locale=0&sourceId=b1747c2fc20b8010VgnVCM1000004d82620a____&vgnextoid=bbd508f54922d010VgnVCM1000004d82620aRCRD) (under Additional Information):

> One ordinance received in the temple is called the endowment. The word endowment means "gift," and the temple endowment truly is a gift from God. The ordinance consists of a series of instructions and includes covenants to live righteously and follow the requirements of the gospel. The endowment focuses on the Savior, His role in Heavenly Father's plan, and the personal commitment of each member to follow Him.

From the Wikipedia article on [Endowment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endowment_%28Mormonism%29):

> The endowment was instituted by founder Joseph Smith, Jr. in the 1840s with further contributions by Brigham Young and his successors. The ceremony is performed in Latter Day Saints' temples, special places dedicated specifically for the endowment and certain other rituals sacred to Mormons, and is closed to all but worthy Mormons. There was a brief period during the construction of the Salt Lake Temple where a small building referred to as the Endowment House was used to perform the ritual. The endowment is currently practiced by the LDS Church, several denominations of Mormon fundamentalism, and a few other Mormon denominations. The LDS Church has simplified its ceremony from the way it existed in the 19th century, and has removed some of the more controversial elements.

According to the LDS church, the endowment ceremony was revealed to Joseph Smith by God.  According to [church detractors](http://www.exmormon.org/journey/journey_g.htm), the endowment ceremony was based on the Masonic initiation ceremony.

As to the specific changes, the Wikipedia Endowment article has a section at the bottom called "Later modifications by the LDS Church".  It's too long a section to quote in the answer.

Comment: One note regarding possible basing on Masonic ceremony. The Masonic ceremony has its roots in King Solomon's Temple. So it is conceivable that the LDS Endowment is a restoration of the same ceremony that the Masonic ceremony is based on, but not actually based on the Masonic ceremony. This would make the two ceremonies siblings or cousins.

Answer (score 1):

Gilbert Le Blanc's answer is very good. More details on how the Mormon Endowment and the rituals of Freemasonry relate are available in the Encyclopedia of Mormonism:

http://eom.byu.edu/index.php/Freemasonry_and_the_Temple

After the first temple ordinances in Nauvoo, some early LDS leaders understood them to be a restoration of true masonry (letter from Heber C. Kimball to Parley P. Pratt, and from the diary of Benjamin F. Johnson).